# Chartboost Delegate not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Desired : I want to do something when Delegates method call Observed :Delegates method not calling Ad's show on the screen successfully
**Error**
code:Chartboost.delegate=self

Error: Type 'Chartboost' has no member 'delegate'

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool  {

    Chartboost.start(withAppId: "4f21c409cd1cb2fb7000001b", appSignature: "92e2de2fd7070327bdeb54c15a5295309c6fcd2d", delegate: nil)

    return true
}
```

**ViewController Code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate,GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate,IMBannerDelegate, IMInterstitialDelegate ,ChartboostDelegate{

    @IBAction func Vedio(_ sender: Any) {

        Chartboost.showRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu)

    }

    @IBAction func LoadFullAd(_ sender: Any) {

        Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen)
    }

     private func shouldDisplayRewardedVideo(_ location: CBLocation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    private func shouldRequestInterstitial(_ location: CBLocation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior? What is the observed behavior? What do you think about this conundrum?

Comment: Desired : I want to do something when Delegates method call
Observed :Delegates method not calling  
Ad's show on the screen successfully

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more complete instead of using comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A had to set the delegate as self with Chartboost.setDelegate(self)

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Chartboost.start(withAppId: "4f21c409cd1cb2fb7000001b", appSignature: "92e2de2fd7070327bdeb54c15a5295309c6fcd2d", delegate:self as ChartboostDelegate)
    Chartboost.setDelegate(self as ChartboostDelegate)

    return true
}
```

After looking at how to properly convert Objective-C methods in Swift, I added the underscore (_), which changed the function to:

```
func shouldDisplayRewardedVideo(_ location: CBLocation) -> Bool
{

    return true
}
 func shouldRequestInterstitial(_ location: CBLocation) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

XCode then gave me a hint that I was close to the delegate method, but needed to change the type of location and I ended up with

```
func shouldDisplayRewardedVideo(_ location: String) -> Bool
{

    return true
}
 func shouldRequestInterstitial(_ location: String) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

Comment: It may not be such a good idea to set the delegate in the AppDelegate class. It is better to set the delegate in the class you intend to use it. In your case that seems to be in the ViewController. Move 'Chartboost.setDelegate(self as ChartboostDelegate)' to the ViewController and implement the delegate's methods there.

Comment: Thanks for the help mmccabe.

Comment: Sure.... no problem. I've been doing a lot of the same stuff recently. BTW: I added a tip on how to autogenerate the delegate methods stubs in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the delegate is set to nil, the class that calls the delegate's methods (in this case Chartboost) will not be able to make the delegate's method calls. You should set the delegate to the 'self' of the class where you have implemented the delegate methods expected by Chartboost.

In the example above, you could set the Chartboost delegate to the 'self' of the ViewController.

For example, inside of ViewController, you have already declared the 'ChartboostDelegate' in the class signature. When you want to turn on the Chartboost delegate methods, assign the ViewController's 'self' to the Chartboost delegate using something like:

```
Chartboost.delegate = self
```

In the case of Chartboost, it looks like the author made the delegate private, so it can be set in the ViewController using:

```
Chartboost.start(withAppId: "some uid", appSignature: "some other uid", delegate: self)
```

or, as later found out:

```
Chartboost.setDelegate(self)
```

(It can also be set in the AppDelegate class by locating the ViewController instance in the storyboard. Not a great fit in this case.)

If you're having problems generating the delegate method's call signature stubs (the method calls expected by the delegate), XCode will autogenerate them for you. Just click on the error message found next to your class declaration:

```
Type '<your class implementing the delegate methods>' does not conform to protocol '<the delegate protocol to implement>'
```

More detail about the error will appear. Click the 'Fix' button and XCode will autogenerate the method stubs for you.

Comment: You can not set delegate directly to class. You have to make instance for that.

Comment: I think developer is using a capital letter to name the variable instance. So should work

Comment: Chartboost is the Class name  Chartboost is not an instance

Comment: Since you are calling Chartboost functions, it must have instantiated somewhere. You can always pass the 'self' to the Chartboost.start() call, by finding the ViewController instance in the storyboard (if using storyboards as most do), in the AppDelegate (the delegate may be private anyway, so this may be the intention of Chartboost author)

Comment: @mmccabe: `Chartboost.delegate = self` will not work. Please run code in your editor first.

Comment: The principle of using delegates work this way, especially if the delegate is public as is generally the case. In the case of Chartboost, it looks like the author made the delegate private, which restricts setting the delegate during the call to Chartboos.start()

Comment: You can set delegate in `Chartboos.start() ` method, no one can restrict you to do so. Check in my code I already set it in start method.But you are trying to access private property from Chartboost.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that an author of a class that uses a delegate protocol can make the delegate private

Comment: Still `Chartboost.delegate = self` will fail to compile. Update your answer.